# "number of slices" shortcut doesn't work (Loop Cut)

Tags: loop

https://youtu.be/zH_eZDWCnMg?t=123

Hi, i try this tutorial but "number of slices" page up/down or mouse wheel shortcut doesn't work ?

Version: 2.8 RC

Comment: Do you have any pictures you could post? there's a variety of reasons this might not be working

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i try with simple cube and i am using "industry compatible" keymap. But I also tried other keymap (blender, blender 2.79)  and they didn't work.

https://ibb.co/gPvvFTR

Comment: Are you pressing ctrl+r and hovering it over the loop, then scrolling?Also, some topology cant loop cut, so that also may be the issue.

Comment: I think "industry compatible" keymap not assigned with this version, classic blender keymaps works with whell or page up.